# My rpm Requires ncompress how do I get this to work on rhel 9 when the package now that the package is obsolete?

Tags: require, rpm, obsolete

We are currently using RHEL 8, but intend to move to RHEL 9.  The rpm I create currently Requires ncompress, which is no longer available so my package can no longer be installed on a new RHEL 9 host.  To resolve this, can I simply have "Requires: compress, uncompress" and let the package figure out where to get them, is there a downside to this?   Is there a way to find what the new package should be (I cannot find documentation for a recommended replacement), or is it better to modify my code to use gzip and gunzip and require that package instead?  Is there another option that I am not thinking of to get around this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up changing the our compress/uncompress functionality to use gzip/gunzip and could remove the requirement.